# Django empty error messages

Tags: django, forms

I have an ajax login view. I can log in ok but when I log in incorrectly my json returns:
    {"errors": {}}
My view is as follows:

```
def ajaxlogin(request):
    from forms import LoginForm
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    logged_in = False
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if request.is_ajax() and user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        logged_in = True
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'redirect' : 'true'}), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'errors': dict(form.errors.items())}), content_type='application/json')
```

Any ideas?

If I use the login function without js enabled the form displays all the relevant error messages.

My LoginForm:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=30,error_messages={'required':_("please enter a username"), 'min_length':_("username must be at least 5 characters"), 'max_length':_("username must be at less than 30 characters")})
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, error_messages={'required':_("please enter a password"), 'min_length':_("password must be at least 6 characters")})

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("you have entered an incorrect username and/or password"))
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This account is inactive."))
        self.check_for_test_cookie()
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: in if request.is_ajax() and user is not None: should that by username or is "user" correct. I don't see a reference to it in your local scope. same is true for the login fucntion

Comment: Im using from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login. 'User' is correct as I'm logging in ok with this ajax view.

Comment: Sorry I missed out a line. Edited

Comment: By incorrect do you mean failed credentials or a validation error in the LoginForm? Because form.error will only give you feedback if there is a validation issue at the form level. So, an empty dict might be the expected result here, if you are simply giving authenticate() bad credentials and it is returning None.

Comment: Failed validation messages. I think maybe I have missed: if form.is_valid(). I will try that.

Comment: OK. if form.is_valid() still returns empty.

Comment: But now login in doesn't work. Must be a problem on the form level

Comment: My point was, if you give the form username XYZ and password 123 the form will happily validate that and return no errors. However, your authentication will fail because there is no username XYZ and password 123. Even if you call form.is_valid() the same result will occur.

Comment: ok. It appears auth is ok. Validation process not.

Comment: You might want to edit and post your form, unless you've figured it out from here

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us what your LoginForm looks like. Assuming it just has two `CharField`s, I wouldn't expect any errors as long as you have provided a user name and password.

To show errors for an invalid username and password combination, your form would have to include logic to authenticate the login data.

Luckily, you don't have write this yourself, you can use Django's built in `AuthenticationForm`. It will return an error if the username and password are not valid.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms imoirt AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

# in the view
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # if the form is valid, the user has provided a valid 
        # username and password. We can get the user with the 
        # form.get_user method and log them in
        auth_login(request, form.get_user())
        # return suitable ajax responses
```

Comment: Solved!!! I had (request.POST) should have been (data=request.POST). Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: I wrote the answer before you posted your authentication form, so I don't know how useful it will be. My only final comment is that you shouldn't be fetching `username` and `password` from `request.POST`. In general, check your form is valid, then get values from `form.cleaned_data`. In this case, you don't even have to fetch the uuse name and password, as the authentication form has the get_user method.

Comment: Ooh, that's an obscure gotcha! On almost every form, `data` is the first argument in the `__init__` method, so `request.POST` would be fine. However the `AuthenticationForm` takes `request` as its first argument, so you *do* need `data=request.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'errors': form.errors.as_text()}), content_type='application/json')
```